# ASP.NET NumericUpDownExtender with button hold support?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am trying to get an "UpDown" button which allows the user to hold the increment/decrement button to quickly and easily increment/decrement a decimal value. I have been trying this using the ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender but this seems to only allow increment/decrement with button clicks. This is rather clunky since the value is a percentage. Any ideas of a better way to handle this within ASP.NET?

Comment: Will this link help you..? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/1372/up-down-extender-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't seem to show how to make this control work with button hold. I want the user to be able to hold the left mouse button to make the values change continuously.

Comment: can you show some code perhaps you can do your own custom keydown event

Comment: Sure, here is a link to the code (I don't have anything in the cs file yet, just aspx) https://gist.github.com/gobotsoup/6fb2fa89a69299f54884

Comment: oh and thanks for the suggestion of using a custom keydown event, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make this pretty simply with javascript using a timer. 
Here is the ASPX part of it:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Factor" runat="server" MaxLength="6" Width="60"/>
<input id ="UpButton" value="&#9650;" type="button" onmousedown="timerID = setInterval(function(){FactUp()},100);" onmouseup="clearInterval(timerID);"/>

<input id ="DownButton" value="&#9660;" type="button" onmousedown="timerID = setInterval(function(){FactDown()},100);" onmouseup="clearInterval(timerID);"/>
```

And the javascript:

```
var timerID = 0;
function FactDown() {
        var obj = document.getElementById('Factor');
        var num = parseFloat(obj.value)
        if (isNaN(num)) {
            return;
        }
        num -=0.01;
        obj.value = num.toFixed(2);            
    }

    function FactUp() {
        var obj = document.getElementById('Factor');
        var num = parseFloat(obj.value);
        if (isNaN(num)) {
            return;
        }
        num += 0.01;
        obj.value = num.toFixed(2);            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add reference on this script to ScriptManager control's Script collection:

```
Sys.Extended.UI.NumericUpDownBehavior.prototype._clearClickInterval = function () {
    if (this._clickInterval != null) {
        window.clearInterval(this._clickInterval);
        this._clickInterval = null;
    }
};

Sys.Extended.UI.NumericUpDownBehavior.prototype._setDownClickInterval = function () {
    this._clearClickInterval();
    this._clickInterval = window.setInterval(this._clickDownHandler, 200);
};

Sys.Extended.UI.NumericUpDownBehavior.prototype._setUpClickInterval = function () {
    this._clearClickInterval();
    this._clickInterval = window.setInterval(this._clickUpHandler, 200);
};

Sys.Extended.UI.NumericUpDownBehavior.prototype.addIntervalHandlers = function () {
    this._clickInterval = null;

    this._buttonMouseUpHandler = Function.createDelegate(this, this._clearClickInterval);

    if (this._bUp) {
        this._upButtonMouseDownHandler = Function.createDelegate(this, this._setUpClickInterval);
        $addHandler(this._bUp, 'mousedown', this._upButtonMouseDownHandler);
        $addHandler(window, 'mouseup', this._buttonMouseUpHandler);
    }

    if (this._bDown) {
        this._downButtonMouseDownHandler = Function.createDelegate(this, this._setDownClickInterval);
        $addHandler(this._bDown, 'mousedown', this._downButtonMouseDownHandler);
        $addHandler(window, 'mouseup', this._buttonMouseUpHandler);
    }
};

var legacyInitialize = Sys.Extended.UI.NumericUpDownBehavior.prototype.initialize,
    legacyDispose = Sys.Extended.UI.NumericUpDownBehavior.prototype.dispose;

Sys.Extended.UI.NumericUpDownBehavior.prototype.initialize = function () {
    legacyInitialize.apply(this);
    this.addIntervalHandlers();
};

Sys.Extended.UI.NumericUpDownBehavior.prototype.dispose = function () {
    legacyDispose.apply(this);
    this._clearClickInterval();

    if (this._upButtonMouseDownHandler) {
        $removeHandler(this._bUp, 'mousedown', this._upButtonMouseDownHandler);
        $removeHandler(window, 'mouseup', this._buttonMouseUpHandler);
        this._upButtonMouseDownHandler = null;
    }

    if (this._downButtonMouseDownHandler) {
        $removeHandler(this._bDown, 'mousedown', this._downButtonMouseDownHandler);
        $removeHandler(window, 'mouseup', this._buttonMouseUpHandler);
        this._downButtonMouseDownHandler = null;
    }

    this._buttonMouseUpHandler = null;
};
```

Not sure, but might be required to call `addIntervalHandlers()` function expicitely on an extender instance.
You can check this script if you'll add at the end this line: `$find("ctl00_SampleContent_NumericUpDownExtender4").addIntervalHandlers()` and execute it from browser's console on this page: [NumericUpDown Demonstration](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/NumericUpDown/NumericUpDown.aspx) The last extender will handle mouse button hold.